# Esse "humilhou-se a si mesmo" da Bíblia é redundante ou tem alguma explicação?

Tags: gramática

Na bíblia, em Filipenses 2:8, temos o seguinte versículo:

> E, achado na forma de homem, **humilhou-se a si mesmo**, sendo obediente até à morte, e morte de cruz.
>
> Filipenses 2:8

Eu destaquei a parte que me chamou atenção de negrito. É que, nos dias atuais, seria motivo de muita chacota se você ouvisse alguém dizendo "ele humilhou-se a si mesmo". Alguém poderia dizer que tal pessoa cometeu um erro, uma redundância.

Mas eu gostaria de saber se isso realmente é uma redundância de acordo com as regras gramaticais, ou se simplesmente tem algum sentido usar "a si mesmo" depois da palavra "humilhou-se" (estou desconsiderando interpretações teológicas).

A frase correta não seria: *humilhou a si mesmo* ou simplesmente *humilhou-se*?

**Atualização**:

Encontrei outros versículos que contém o mesmo exemplo da aparente redundância, apenas para reforçar que a forma de escrita não foi usada apenas no versículo acima:

> Porque não é aprovado quem **a si mesmo se louva**, mas, sim, aquele a quem o Senhor louva.
> 2 Coríntios 10:18

> Porque não ousamos classificar-nos, ou comparar-nos com alguns, que **se louvam a si mesmos**; mas estes que **se medem a si mesmos**, e se comparam consigo mesmos, estão sem entendimento.
> 2 Coríntios 10:12

**Nota**: Versículos acima foram retirados da Bíblia *Almeida Corrigida e Revisada Fiel*

Comment: Sabes, o pessoal gosta muito de passar sentença. Depois apanha umas manias e repete-as acriticamente, como que todo o pleonasmo é vício. O pleonasmo é figura de estilo; só é vício se empregue à toa. Encontra-se essa construção na melhor literatura em língua portuguesa: [desprezar-se a si mesmo (Erico Veríssimo, 1961)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=ON4QAQAAMAAJ&q=%22levava+a+desprezar-se+a+si+mesmo%22&dq=%22levava+a+desprezar-se+a+si+mesmo%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi-1NbosP_UAhVMVRQKHSMCD3EQ6AEIJTAA) >>

Comment: >> [via-se a si mesmo (Machado de Assis)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=8bdcAAAAQBAJ&pg=PT38&dq=%22via-se+a+si+mesmo%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi-tLykqv_UAhVIUhQKHV94BfkQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=%22via-se%20a%20si%20mesmo%22&f=false), *examinou-se a si mesmo* (José Saramago, 1989); [devorava-se a si mesmo (Alexandre Herculano)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=XnJPAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA191&dq=%22Devorava-se+a+si+mesmo%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjJnrKSsP_UAhVHNxQKHfBxCu4Q6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=%22Devorava-se%20a%20si%20mesmo%22&f=false)

Comment: A vulgata (tradução latina da bíblia) usa, nos trechos que citaste, a expressão **se ipsum(a) + VERBO** (isto é, **a si mesmo(a) se + VERBO**), que também pode ser considerada como pleonasmo, pois usar apenas o pronome reflexivo **se** já seria suficiente. Em Coríntios II 10:18 usa-se ainda o pronome composto [**seipse**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/seipse), formado pela união daqueles.  Creio que a escolha de **a si mesmo se louva** em 10:18 na tradução portuguesa é de caráter semântico (tal como respondido por Artefacto) e remete à escolha de **seipsum commendat** na tradução vulgata.

Comment: PS: **ipsum(a)** = **a si mesmo(a)**, e **commendare** = **louvar**. Mas a minha bíblia traduz "commendare" como "recomendar", que seria a tradução literal e etimologicamente fiel.

Comment: não seria o "se" partícula apassivadora "ele foi humilhado por si mesmo"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Não há nada de extraordinário nessas frases. Pessoalmente, creio que ficam melhor com o reforço *a si mesmo* dada a infrequência do uso reflexivo dos verbos em questão ou da necessidade de contraste (em 2 Coríntios 10:18)

O análise tradicional é a de que ***se*** é pronome reflexo e expressão anafórica cujo valor referencial está ligado ao do sujeito (geralmente) e que ***si mesmo/próprio*** é um reforço do reflexo. Aliás, a possibilidade de existir reforço com *mesmo/próprio* é um teste usado para determinar a reflexividade de *se* (cf. **ele admira-se a si mesmo com o estado da situação*, onde *se* é *inerente* ou *pseudo-reflexo*).

Nalguns casos, o reforço pode ser necessário para fazer a desambiguação entre a leitura reflexa e a leitura recíproca: (*eles louvaram-se **a si mesmos*** *vs.* *eles louvaram-se **uns aos outros***).

Comment: Também para forçar uma leitura reflexa em vez de inerente: *convencer-se a si mesmo, enganar-se a si mesmo, magoar-se a si mesmo.*

Answer (score 1):

Existem dois tipos de pleonasmo: o **pleonasmo vicioso** e o **pleonasmo literário**.

O **Pleonasmo Vicioso**, também chamado de redundância, é um vício de linguagem. É um erro sintático não intencional que a pessoa comete por desconhecimento das normas gramaticais.

Exemplos:
"Subir para cima": o verbo “subir” já indica ir para cima, elevar-se.
"Descer para baixo": o verbo “descer” já denota mover de cima para baixo, declinar.
"Entrar para dentro": o verbo “entrar” já indica passar para dentro.
"sair para fora": o verbo “sair” é sempre passar de dentro para fora, afastar-se.

**Pleonasmo Literário**
Já o **pleonasmo literário** (ou intencional) é usado com intenção poética de oferecer maior expressividade ao texto. Assim, nesse caso ele é considerado uma figura de linguagem.

Em outras palavras, o pleonasmo literário é utilizado intencionalmente como recurso estilístico e semântico para reforçar o discurso de seu enunciador. Observe que nesse viés, o escritor tem 'licença poética' para fazer essa ligação.

Exemplos:

“E rir meu riso e derramar meu pranto” (Vinicius de Moraes)
“E ali dançaram tanta dança” (Chico Buarque e Vinicius de Moraes)
“Me sorri um sorriso pontual e me beija com a boca de hortelã” (Chico Buarque)

Na Bíblia, que é um livro traduzido em excelente e exemplar português altamente erudito, temos inúmeros exemplos de pleonasmo literário, construídos por meio da repetição do pronome oblíquo, gerando um pleonasmos literário de grande efeito comunicativo:

"E, achado na forma de homem, **humilhou-se a si mesmo**, sendo obediente até à morte, e morte de cruz." (Filipenses 2:8)

"**Examine-se, pois, o homem a si mesmo**, e assim coma deste pão, e beba deste cálice." (1Cor 11:28 - Almeida Revista e Corrigida)

"Depois disto ouvi a voz do Senhor, que dizia: A quem enviarei, e quem irá por nós? Então disse eu: Eis-me aqui, **envia-me a mim**." (Isaías 6:8 Versão Almeida Revista e Atualizada).

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: +1 E cf. ['"Criar um novo ..." é redundante?'](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/5378/2764) para mais nuance em relação ao **pleonasmo** *aparentemente* **vicioso**.