# "Criar um novo ..." é redundante?

Tags: redundâncias

Quando eu digo por exemplo "Criar uma nova loja", o `nova` é considerado redundante?
Se eu estou a criar alguma coisa possivelmente será uma coisa nova, mas "Criar uma loja" parece que falta alguma coisa.
[image: Word mostra que é redundante]

Comment: Se criar um novo x fosse redundante, a palavra novo não serve para grande coisa.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ser ou não redundância frequentemente depende do contexto: até o famigerado "subir para cima" deixa de ser redundante num contexto em que "cima" significa um lugar específico (como um dado cômodo no andar de cima, ou um dado apartamento num prédio). Além disso, as pessoas têm diferentes níveis de tolerância a construções com algum grau de redundância.

Aqui não é diferente: aos meus ouvidos "criar um novo" é aceitável (mas não aos [dessa escritora](http://writing.rocks/annals-of-redundancy-annals/)), apesar de "criar" significar fazer com que algo que não existia antes passe a existir e, nesse sentido, é sempre novo; além disso, "novo" pode ser referir, por exemplo, ao *tipo de loja*, ou ainda enfatizar que se trata de mais uma, distinta, em que "nova" significaria "outra", "diferente".

Mas vale notar que talvez "abrir" seja preferível a "criar":
"Abrir uma nova/outra loja";
"Abrir uma loja diferente".

E, se de fato houver algo novo além da loja em si, se pode deixar isto explícito, por exemplo:
"Abrir uma loja de outro produto"
"Abrir uma loja voltada a outra clientela"
"Criar/abrir um novo tipo de loja".

Comment: Pois o exemplo "loja" poderá não ter sido o melhor. A pergunta era mesma para o caso `criar um novo ...` (qualquer coisa que adequasse)

Comment: Foi  como tinha entendido, @André - apenas os dois parágrafos finais são mais específicos para o exemplo da loja, o restante do texto se refere ao caso geral de "criar um novo" ou pode ser adaptado.

Comment: Concordo, ipsis litteris.

Answer (score 3):

Não acho que seja redundante.  Na verdade, vejo uma diferença semântica entre "criar uma loja" e "criar uma nova loja".

- "vamos criar uma loja" significa que ainda não criamos loja alguma, seja lá qual for o significado de loja no contexto; estabelecimento comercial, templo maçônico, etc.  Vamos criar uma loja, não um teatro ou um cinema.

já,

- "vamos criar uma nova loja" indica que já existe(m) loja(s) e que vamos criar mais uma.