# Goteira é sempre no teto?

Tags: significado-em-contexto, pleonasmo

Estou há mais de uma semana em um debate sobre o mínimo de informação necessária durante uma conversa ao se definir uma goteira.

O cerne da questão é o seguinte:
"Goteira no teto", é um pleonasmo completamente desnecessário, ou é uma clarificação bem vinda?

Comment: Boas-vindas ao Portuguese SE, LeoFuso, e obrigado pela contribuição. Me permiti alterar o título da pergunta para um que, ao meu ver, melhor reflete o cerne da questão, mas por favor se sinta à vontade para reverter a mudança.

Answer (score 4):

É quase sempre desnecessário.

A palavra "goteira" até tem outros significados, além de:

> **4** buraco ou falha no material de cobertura de uma casa, por onde penetra água de chuva e escorre ou pinga no interior ‹*morava num sobrado cheio de goteiras*›  (Houaiss)

mas este é o que é, em minha experiência, mais usado, tornando a clarificação "no teto" pouco necessária e, pior, pouco efetiva, dado que outro significado importante de "goteira" é "calha" — que também se costuma encontrar no teto. Portanto a expressão "goteira no teto" permaneceria ambígua numa situação em que pudesse haver esta ambiguidade.

Contudo, como a palavra pode denotar também a própria água que penetra na casa desta forma, construções como "goteira na parede" são possíveis e, portanto, "goteira no teto" seria mais precisa numa situação em que outras possibilidades são relevantes.

---

Nota: sobre pleonasmos em geral, vale consultar as postagens em [O que é considerado pleonasmo?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/150/2764) e ["Criar um novo ..." é redundante?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/5378/2764), entre outras, mas a essência da mensagem é: depende. Depende, acima de tudo, do contexto (como de hábito), e também não se pode esquecer que, além dos pleonasmos viciosos (a serem evitados, via de regra), há outros, como os de ênfase ("ver com seus próprios olhos").