# "Aprender coisas novas" é um pleonasmo?

Tags: figuras-de-linguagem, literatura, linguagem, pleonasmo

Existem dois tipos de pleonasmos: pleonasmo literário e pleonasmo vicioso.
O pleonasmo literário é utilizado para destacar uma ideia, sendo muito encontrado na linguagem literária. Nesse caso, o pleonasmo não é considerado erro, encaixando-se no que conhecemos como “licença poética”.

Entendo que "Aprender coisas novas" tem este sentido poético.
E acredito que podemos aprender coisas que não são novas...

Comment: É como vejo também, inclusive, "novas" em que sentido, e para quem? Essa outra postagem responde à sua pergunta: ["Criar um novo ..." é redundante?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/5378/2764)